# Have only info from Group Footer in Cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab

We have a status field that changes from time to time for client

The raw data would look like this

```
Client      Status      Date of Status  
001          Current      12/5/17
001          Overdrawn    3/13/18
001          Current      4/1/18  
002          Overdrawn    1/13/18
002          Current      1/16/18
003          Current      2/1/18
003          Surplus      5/3/18
```

For the purposes of our report we want to show the most recent status for each client. So we group by each client and then suppress everything but the group footer giving us:

```
Client       Status      Date of Status    
001          Current      4/1/18   
002          Current      1/16/18
003          Surplus      5/3/18
```

We want to run a cross tab so we can get totals for the most recent values but it looks like the cross tab is only producing the first entries. Is there a way to get the cross tab to report on just what appears in the group footer?

Comment: Place crosstab in group footer

Comment: But I want to look at all groups in one cross tab

Comment: you need to use calculated fields in cross tab

Comment: What do you mean by calculated fields?